# Any cool function to replace readln from pascal in ansi c?

Tags: c, linux, pascal, readline

The readln reads until the end of line (enter pressed) with spaces and everything,

I would like something like that but for ansi c (not c++ and need to be for linux and windows)

I know that I can make a function that reads every char until the enter pressed but If there is anything cooler it would be great =D

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scanf` with a scanset conversion something like this:

```
char buffer[256];
scanf("%255[^\n]", buffer);
```

another possibility is to use `fgets`:

```
char buffer[256];
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

On Linux (and other POSIX-ish systems) you should probably also have a function named (surprise, surprise) `readline` that's similar, but will allocate the space necessary for the incoming data.

Comment: may I ask what's the difference between using scanf and fgets in performance?

Comment: @Saikios: I'd be surprised if there was a significant difference in performance. The primary reason to use scanf would be if you're using it otherwise, so if (for example) you want to read two `int`s, then the rest of the line you could use `"%d %d %[^\n]"`.

Comment: new question for you,
first: while (1){scanf("%255[^\n]", buffer); printf("%s",buffer);}
second:while (1){fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);printf("%s",buffer);}

the first code print while 1 times the first text
the second code do what I like that is just print it once. Why?

Comment: @Saikios: It's probably better to ask that as a separate question -- in particular, with the poor formatting supported in comments, it's a bit difficult to be sure I've read your code correctly. In general, however, you'd want `while (1==scanf(...` or `while (fgets(...`, rather than `while (1) ...`

Comment: I'm reading some of the documentation to try to understand, but I will stay with the fgets for what I read, thanks Jerry.

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://www.mrx.net/c/readfunctions.html) there is fgets that does this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct. And, worse, why is the cowardly downvote anonymous and uncommented?

Comment: Thank's pete, I think I can't select more than 1 accepted answer, but really thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

Use [fscanf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/).

Comment: my computer didn't like that :P "thing.c:(.text+0x30): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used."