# Reading words till the end of line

Tags: c, scanf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any cool function to replace readln from pascal in ansi c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772531/any-cool-function-to-replace-readln-from-pascal-in-ansi-c)

I have encountered a problem several times that how to read words to the end of line?
for example:
`2

hello this is a word

hi five

so i want to output

case 1:

hello

this

is

word

case 2:

hi

five`

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through each char in the string and when you encounter an `\n` or `\r` character. Something like this maybe?:

```
char str[] = "Hello this is a word\nhi five";
int i;

for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if(str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\r') //do something with str[i]
    else //do something if a new line char is found
}
```

This way you could choos exactly what you want to do in the event of a new line. I tend to use this method a lot when parsing files, I write each line to a buffer, process the buffer, and then begin moving the next line into the buffer for processing.

Answer (score -1):

One of the dangerous function will provide you the solution that is named as `gets`.

Otherwise:-

```
char line[512];
int count=0;
char input=1;
while((input=getchar())!='\n')
    line[count++]=input;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, dataSize=0;

    scanf("%d%*[\n]", &dataSize);
    for(i = 1; i<=dataSize;++i){
        char word[64];
        char *p=word, ch=0;
        printf("case %d:\n", i);
        while(EOF!=ch && '\n'!=ch){
            switch(ch=getchar()){
              case ' '://need multi space char skip ?
              case '\t':
              case '\n':
              case EOF:
                *p = '\0';
                printf("%s\n", p=word);
                break;
              default:
                *p++ = ch;
            }
        }
        if(ch == EOF)break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    int i, dataSize=0;

    scanf("%d%*[\n]", &dataSize);
    for(i = 1; i<=dataSize;++i){
        char word[64],ch = 0;
        int stat = !EOF;
        printf("case %d:\n", i);
        while(EOF!=stat && '\n'!=ch){
            ch = 0;
            stat=scanf(" %s%c", word, &ch);
            if(EOF!=stat || isspace(ch)){
                printf("%s\n", word);
            }
        }
        if(EOF==stat)break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```